# Minimal data structure to prevent 2D-grid traveler from repeat itself

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate of some thread, but I'm really not sure how to describe the question.

I'm wondering what is the **minimal data structure to prevent 2D-grid traveler from repeating itself (i.e. travel to some point it already traveled before)**. The traveler can only move horizontally or vertically 1 step each time. For my special case (below), the 2D-grid is actually a **lower-left triagle** where one coordinate never exceeds another.

For example, with 1D case, this can be simply done by recording the direction of last travel. If direction changes, it's repeating itself.

For 2D case it becomes complicated. **The most trivial way would be creating a list recording the points traveled before, but I'm wondering are there more efficient ways to do that?**

I'm implementing a more-or-less "4-finger" algorithm for *4-sum* where the 2 fingers in the middle moves in two directions (namely `i`, `j`, `k`, and `l`):

```
  i=>    <=j=>     <=k=>       <=l
1 2 3 ... 71 72 ... 123 124 ... 201 202 203
```

The directions fingers travel are decided (or suggested) by some algorithm but might lead to forever-loop. Therefore, I have to force not to take some suggestion if the 2 fingers in the middle starts to repeat history position.

#### EDIT

Among these days, I found 2 solutions. None of them is ideal solution to this problem, but they're at least somewhat usable:

- As @Sorin mentioned below, one solution would be saving a bit array representing state of all cells. For the triangular-grid example here, we can even condense the array to cut memory cost by half (though requiring `k^2` time to compute the bit position where `k` is the degree of freedom i.e. 2 here. A standard array would use only linear time).
- Another solution would be directly avoid backward-travelling. Set up the algorithm such that `j` and `k` only move in one direction (this is probably greedy).

But still since the 2D-grid traveler have the nice property that it moves along axis 1 step each time, I'm wondering are there more "specialized" representation
for this kind of movement.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try DFS or BFS?

Comment: @bishal That's still directly or indirectly maintaining a list

Comment: You could implement the 4-finger solution on each row. Wouldn't be too hard. You'd have to maintain `i, j, k, l` for each row. Assuming a large grid, that's going to be a whole lot less expensive (space wise) than a hash table or a bit array.

Comment: On second thought, that might be more complicated than it first appears.

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis: The DFS solution may not be bad. For a balanced tree it requires _O(log N)_, rather than _O(N)_ memory. That is, a DFS will maintain the list it needs and no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for optimal lookup complexity, then a hashset is the best thing. You need O(N) memory but all lookups & insertions will be O(1).

If it's often that you visit most of the cells then you can even skip the hash part and store a bit array. That is store one bit for every cell and just check if the corresponding bit is 0 or 1. This is much more compact in memory (at least 32x, one bit vs. one int, but likely more as you also skip storing some pointers internal to the datastructure, 64 bits).

If this still take too much space, you could use a bloom filter ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)), but that will give you some false positives (tells you that you've visited a cell, but in fact you didn't). If that's something you can live with the space savings are fairly huge.

Other structures like BSP or Kd-trees could work as well. Once you reach a point where everything is either free or occupied (ignoring the unused cells in the upper triangle) you can store all that information in a single node.
This is hard to recommend because of it's complexity and that it will likely also use O(N) memory in many cases, but with a larger constant. Also all checks will be O(logN).

Comment: I understand hash lookup would be the fastest general purpose algorithm. But like the 1D case would only take 1 bit to record (instead of a whole hash pool), I'm wondering for this kind of up-down-left-right-1-step movement, is there more "interesting" or highly-efficient (but lossless) way to ckeck repeat